# keyboard shortcut for mouse right click

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse

What combination of keys produce a right-click and a left-click?

Comment: You should probably specify the OS, and window manager (if applicable).

Comment: windows7 system

Answer (score 114):

There isn't one for left-click, though <kbd>spacebar</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> are often usable.

Right-clicking is usually a request for a context-sensitive menu which is performed on the keyboard either by typing

- <kbd>≣ Menu</kbd> key (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key),
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>,
- or sometimes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

About 65% of applications out there won't respond to the keyboard request for a context menu, because Windows programmers typically code WM_RBUTTONUP rather than the correct WM_CONTEXTMENU.  Coding the latter allows for the correct action in response to the keyboard.

Comment: +1 for "menu/pointer looking thing usually to the right of the space bar between Alt and Ctrl". Thanks.

Comment: +1 for Shift+F10 as my stupid Logitech keyboard at work doesn't have the context key, it has a Fn key instead. If I could another +1 for the tip on trigger events too.

Comment: Ironically, SQL Server Management Studio falls within the 65%. ;-\

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 oddly enough, my Logitech keyboard has a <kbd>FN</kbd> inbetween the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys, right of the <kbd>SPACE</kbd>. If I press the <kbd>FN</kbd> key and left click, I get a context menu.

Comment: Got stuck RDPing to a server and was trying to right click in a VM with no mouse; Shift+F10 saved the day.

Comment: Never noticed the "menu/pointer looking thing usually to the right of the space bar..." key until now...

Comment: @BradChristie I'm not sure which version of SSMS you used, but it looks like they fixed that at least in SQL 2016.

Comment: @GibralterTop: Good to know. I believe I was using 2014 but can't be certain. Either way, I'm glad it works now. (Maybe they're SO/SE users and saw my comment). ;-)

Answer (score 24):

You can define your own using software like autohotkey:

### Example

This code replaces:

- left alt to left mouse click
- right alt to right mouse click

Code:

```
LAlt::LButto
RAlt::RButton
```

Link to autohotkey keyboard remapping: [link](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm)
Link to autohotkey download : [link](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/)

Comment: If you're actually after the context menu (and not a physical rt-click) use `~RAlt::AppsKey` in your AutoHotKey script.

Answer (score 2):

I have a new Logitech K740 keyboard. It just replaced my old Dell letters-scratched-off key board that had built-in context menu selection and calculator shortcut keys.

The solution to the context menu issue on the Logitech K740 is <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>PrintScrn</kbd> (shows a little page or list). This key combo pops open the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a keyboard equivalent of right-click in PuTTY (or SuperPuTTY) which does a paste, shift+insert does a paste